# AJAX JSON Как словить ответ, если не ответ не json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Отправляю запрос на сервер через AJAX. На сервере очень тяжелый алгоритм с кучей классов и функций. В результате он должен возвратить данные в формате JSON. Иногда все срабатывает нормально, но иногда логика "проходит по другому пути" и возвращает undefined parsererror. Я понимаю, что у меня ошибка в программе и мне сервер возвращает строку с описание ошибки. В коде я не могу найти, где именно эта ошибка. И мне нужно взглянуть на эту строку, что бы исправить алгоритм. Можно ли как-то словить что  dataType: не "json" или еще как-то словить и вывести эту ошибку?

Comment: ....отладка....

Comment: как ни странно, но откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере (ф12)  вкладку Сеть, и смотрите все ваши XHR запросы, там и тело ответа увидите. Либо [отловите исключение при парсинге ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4467327/1216425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  ...,
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + status + ", " + error);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: это надо от сервера получить нечто из области HTTP 4xx-5xx, а тут то скорее всего 200 ОК возвращается, просто вместо ожидаемого JSON какой то текст с варнингами и еще чем то.

Comment: @teran если в `ajax` стоит `dataType: "json"`, a oтвет не может быть распарсен как JSON, то будет вызван обработчик `error`

Comment: вот и добавьте это в код ответа :) там про `dataType` ничего нет. А при вызове с помощью `$.get/post` тип контента определяется автоматически, и подобной ошибки не будет

Comment: console.log(xhr.responseText); - это то, что надо. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function(json) {
      var qwe = qwe.json;
      if (typeof qwe !== "object") {
        stat = JSON.parse(qwe)
}
```